# axios get request to mongodb returns empty data

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, axios

I make an axios request from the frontend through node to a Mongodb database requesting a userName based on userId. The request comes back as having been made, but no data is returned.

This is the Mongodb users collection:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e1b46cb2e6f4c98904598b0"),
    "userId" : "foo@baz.com",
    "userName" : "Fool",
}
```

This is the 'Users' schema file

```
users model: 

const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const UserSchema = new Schema({
    userId: String,
    userName: String,
  });

module.exports = mongoose.model('Users', UserSchema);
```

This is the backend request:

```
backend: 
const express = require('express');
const UserRoute = express.Router();
const Users = require('../Models/UserModel');

UserRoute.route('/fetchUserName').get(function (req, res) {
  Users.find({userId: req.query.userId}, {userName: 1})
    .exec(function (err, user) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
      res.json(err);
    } else {
      console.log(user.data);
      res.json(user.data);
    }
  });
});
```

Here is the actual request from the frontend:

```
getUserName = () => 
 axios.get('http://localhost:4000/Users/fetchUserName', {params: {userId: 'foo@baz.com'}})
   .then(res => {
       return res.data;
   });
};
```

res.data is returned as an empty string.

Any ideas why the request does not work.

Comment: code snippet here would be really helpful

Comment: Is `user.data` the expected value? Where are you validating `res.data` as being empty?

Comment: Maybe you just want to return `user` instead of `user.data`.

Comment: It looks like you're not handling the `axios.get` promise correctly, but would need a repeatable example or more information about the debugging to confirm.

Answer (score 1):

The userId should probably send as a string.
So either:

```
const params {
  userId: 'foo@baz.com'
}
axios.get('http://localhost:4000/Users/fetchUserName', { params })
```

or

```
axios.get('http://localhost:4000/Users/fetchUserName', {params: {userId: 'foo@baz.com'}})
```

Comment: Thanks I forgot the quotes in the question. I fixed the question. I am sending a string, but I still get back no data.

Comment: @ChaimOchs My guess would be then that userName is not valid. I don't remember it that clearly but i suppose that input is not valid. So try to execute the query without the userName. As of now it's probably searching for an object with an userName equal to 1.

Comment: The second object is the 'project' parameter, which tells the database which field to return. There is a userName field, as you can plainly see. In any case, find() with no parameters does not work either.